# Google Analytics get absolute numbers instead of charts

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics Embed API to create a craft Dashboard widgets to show analytics data but now I have to show a number instead of a chart is there a easy and fast way to get just one number?

I'm currently doing something like this

```
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
     'start-date': '30daysAgo',
     'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
});
```

But I want to show something like:
[image]
I'm new to this so any help is welcome

Comment: You are specifically requesting a chart in your code. If you want data you have to use the data object https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing things incorrectly, you are invoking a function to create a chart out from the data retrieved. If you try your query on [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Adate), it'll return a list of sessions per date as specified in your `metrics` which fetch the sessions as per `ga:sessions` value and separated by date by `ga:date` in your `dimensions` key.

You can just use the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#introduction) to do the query and get the number immediately. And so to get the magic number as per your requirement, you just need to leave out the `dimensions` just like this [query](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions).

NOTE: It could vary from sesions, pageviews, users, etc.

Hope this helps.